# RootLogger to output different levels to different files

Tags: log4j

I want to have log4j output INFO level to info.log and DEBUG level to debug.log, so that with this piece of code:

```
logger.info("This is an info message");
logger.debug("This is a debug message");
```

only the first would go to info.log, while both would go to debug.log.

This doesn't work:

```
log4j.rootLogger=INFO, R, T

# A1 is set to be a ConsoleAppender.
log4j.appender.A1=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender

# A1 uses PatternLayout.
log4j.appender.A1.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.A1.layout.ConversionPattern=%r %-5p %c %x - %m%n

log4j.appender.R=org.apache.log4j.FileAppender
log4j.appender.R.File=info.log
log4j.appender.R.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.R.layout.ConversionPattern=%p %t %c - %m%n
log4j.appender.R.Threshold = INFO

log4j.appender.T=org.apache.log4j.FileAppender
log4j.appender.T.File=debug.log
log4j.appender.T.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.T.layout.ConversionPattern=%p %t %c - %m%n
log4j.appender.T.Threshold = DEBUG
```

Neither does this:

```
log4j.rootLogger=INFO, R
log4j.rootLogger=DEBUG, T

log4j.appender.R=org.apache.log4j.FileAppender
log4j.appender.R.File=info.log
log4j.appender.R.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.R.layout.ConversionPattern=%p %t %c - %m%n
log4j.appender.R.Threshold = INFO

log4j.appender.T=org.apache.log4j.FileAppender
log4j.appender.T.File=debug.log
log4j.appender.T.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.T.layout.ConversionPattern=%p %t %c - %m%n
log4j.appender.T.Threshold = DEBUG
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a filter, `org.apache.log4j.varia.LevelMatchFilter`. e.g.:

```js
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE log4j:configuration PUBLIC "-//log4j/log4j Configuration//EN"
                                     "log4j.dtd">
<log4j:configuration xmlns:log4j="http://jakarta.apache.org/log4j/">

    <!-- INFO appender -->
    <appender name="INFOFILE" class="org.apache.log4j.FileAppender">
        <param name="file" value="info.log" />
        <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
            <param name="conversionPattern"
                value="%d{yyyyMMdd-HHmmss.SSS} %-5p (%c.java:%L).%M - %m%n" />
        </layout>
        <filter class="org.apache.log4j.varia.LevelMatchFilter">
            <param name="levelToMatch" value="INFO" />
        </filter>
    </appender>

    <!-- DEBUG appender -->
    <appender name="DEBUGFILE" class="org.apache.log4j.FileAppender">
        <param name="file" value="debug.log" />
        <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
            <param name="conversionPattern"
                value="%d{yyyyMMdd-HHmmss.SSS} %-5p (%c.java:%L).%M - %m%n" />
        </layout>
        <filter class="org.apache.log4j.varia.LevelMatchFilter">
            <param name="levelToMatch" value="DEBUG" />
        </filter>
    </appender>

    <!-- root -->
    <root>
        <priority value="ALL" />
        <appender-ref ref="INFOFILE" />
        <appender-ref ref="DEBUGFILE" />
    </root>

</log4j:configuration>
```

Put all this in one file in the default package: `log4j.xml`.